# Python Polar Plot Issue

Tags: python, matplotlib

My data ends at around 23 hours but it keeps looping like the image shown below:
[image]

Code:

```
ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax.plot(x,y)

ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax.set_theta_offset(pi/2.0)
ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(0, 2*pi, 24, endpoint=False))
ax.set_xticklabels(range(24))
ax.set_yticks((0.300,0.350,0.400,0.450,0.500,0.550,0.600))
ax.set_ylim([0.3,0.6])
ax.set_yticklabels(('300','350','400','450','500','550','600'))

plt.show()
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your problem? Please click the [edit] link and add an explanation of what’s not working.

Comment: Looks like matplotlib is plotting exactly what you asked it to plot. Note that your `x` values will be interpreted as radians. Maybe you want to scale them by `2*pi / 24` before passing them to `plot`.

Comment: Thanks, I just needed to convert it to radians

Answer (score 0):

You have to transform your x-Axis defined in ax.plot to range from 0 to 2*PI.
e.g. x[:] = x[:]/(2.*pi) before ax.plot